# Booting to grub if Ubuntu USB is unplugged

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, 15.10

I installed ubuntu 15.10 on usb, I am using macbook pro and I installed grub in ubuntu. When I insert usb, everything works fine. But I met some problem. When I did not insert usb, I got into grub command line. Although, I could reboot and press option and I can get into mac system.

What can I do? I want to ignore grub command line when I do not insert usb and get automatically into mac system.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you chose to install GRUB in your USB drive rather than in the computer's disk. Boot into the Live media and run, in a Terminal window:

`sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt`

replacing X with Ubuntu's partition number, and then

`sudo grub-install /dev/sda --root-directory=/mnt`

should do it.

- Note: in the second command do **not** put any number after `sda`.